# Mysql not my strong suit Error #1064

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9' at line 13

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.11.1.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Feb 06, 2014 at 02:53 PM
-- Server version: 4.0.27
-- PHP Version: 4.4.8


--
-- Database: `anstas`
--
CREATE DATABASE `anstas`;
USE anstas;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_dictionary_disciplines`
--

CREATE TABLE `tbl_dictionary_disciplines` (
  `disciplineid` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `discipline` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`disciplineid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`disciplineid`),
  KEY `id_2` (`disciplineid`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_dictionary_disciplines`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_dictionary_disciplines` VALUES(1, 'Taxonomy');
INSERT INTO `tbl_dictionary_disciplines` VALUES(2, 'Control');
INSERT INTO `tbl_dictionary_disciplines` VALUES(3, 'Pathways');
INSERT INTO `tbl_dictionary_disciplines` VALUES(4, 'Ecology');
INSERT INTO `tbl_dictionary_disciplines` VALUES(5, 'Physiology');
INSERT INTO `tbl_dictionary_disciplines` VALUES(6, 'General');
INSERT INTO `tbl_dictionary_disciplines` VALUES(7, 'Genetics');
INSERT INTO `tbl_dictionary_disciplines` VALUES(8, 'Laws & Policy');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
```

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: "PHP Version: 4.4.8" ... "Server version: 4.0.27" ... are you a time traveler from the year 2000?

Answer (score 1):

`TYPE` is obsolete, and hence is the error.

USE

`ENGINE=MyISAM`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl_dictionary_disciplines ( disciplineid int(6) 
                                     NOT NULL auto_increment, discipline varchar(50) 
                                     NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KEY (disciplineid), 
                                     UNIQUE KEY id (disciplineid), KEY id_2 (disciplineid) ) 
   ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```